# Jquery Autocomplete starts with first letter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code

```
<div>
    <label for="dynamicSearch">Search:</label>
    <input id="dynamicSearch">
</div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
 // autocomplete
    $("#dynamicSearch").autocomplete({
        source: "dynamicSearch.php",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

dynamicSearch.php

```
<?php
$con = pg_connect("connection");
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . pg_last_error());
  }

  $dynamicSearch = "SELECT name from bkash_dist WHERE name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%' LIMIT 10";

  $result = pg_query($con, $dynamicSearch);



    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
      {      
            $results[] = array('label' => $row['distrbutor']);
            }



pg_close($con);
$encoded = json_encode($results); 

// send response back to index.html
// and end script execution
die($encoded)
?>
```

When I am searching with **"A**" its giving all result those contains "**A**" but I want **those start** with "**A**" or "**a**" (case sensitive). How can I do it?

Comment: Post your query (php code).

Comment: You did not mention the code you are using to search items in dynamicSearch.php. I believe the filtering happens on that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the *SQL query* so it only looks for the beggining of the *result* :

```
$dynamicSearch = "SELECT name from bkash_dist 
                  WHERE name
                  LIKE '"$_GET['term']."%'
                  LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This solution is for the first letter. Can you say How can I remove the case sensitivity.

Comment: @Md.AzizulAlam `SELECT LOWER(name) FROM...` is to lowercase the letters and `SELECT UPPER(name) FROM...` to uppercase.

Comment: at first sight i didnt get the diff in answer :) Great soln and simplest work around other than using regex in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What is in your dynamicSearch.php?

Look at [this example in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1). It does exactly what you want